# Inlining SQL functions in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, index, postgis

I am defining a new data type `tpointp` for storing trajectories of moving objects. One function associated to this data type is `atPeriod(tpointp, tsrange)` which projects the full trajectory to a time period represented as a timestamp range (`tsrange`).

```
CREATE FUNCTION atPeriod(tpointp, tsrange)
    RETURNS tpointp
    AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'temporalp_at_period'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

This function can be used in queries like the following one

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT atPeriod(Trip, Period) AS Trip
FROM QueryPeriods, berlinmod_trip
-- Call the temporal index if any
WHERE getTime(Trip) && Period 

Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..475.50 rows=898 width=32)
  ->  Seq Scan on queryperiods  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=100 width=24)
  ->  Index Scan using berlinmod_trip_temporal_gist_idx on berlinmod_trip  (cost=0.14..2.30 rows=18 width=104)
        Index Cond: (gettime(trip) && queryperiods.period)
```

As it is done in PostGIS, I would like to use inlining for implicitly calling any potential indexes. That would allow the user to remove the `WHERE` clause in the above query. I rewrote the definition of the function `atPeriod()` above as follows.

```
CREATE FUNCTION _atPeriod(tpointp, tsrange)
    RETURNS tpointp
    AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'temporalp_at_period'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION atPeriod(tpointp, tsrange)
    RETURNS tpointp
    AS 'SELECT @extschema@._atPeriod($1,$2) WHERE getTime($1) OPERATOR(@extschema@.&&) $2'
    LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;
```

However with the new definition there is no implicit index call

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT atPeriod(Trip, Period) AS Trip
FROM QueryPeriods, berlinmod_trip

Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..47224.47 rows=179700 width=32)
  ->  Seq Scan on berlinmod_trip  (cost=0.00..49.97 rows=1797 width=104)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3.50 rows=100 width=24)
        ->  Seq Scan on queryperiods  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=100 width=24)
```

In PostgreSQL there are several conditions to enable inlining SQL functions: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions

However, I was not able to understand why this doesn't work for the function `atPeriod()`.

Notice that this works for `boolean` functions. I have another function `intersects()` which generalizes the `ST_Intersects` topological operator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _intersects(tpointp, geometry)
    RETURNS boolean
    AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'intersects_tpointp_geom'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION intersects(tpointp, geometry)
    RETURNS boolean
    AS 'SELECT trajectory($1) OPERATOR(@extschema@.&&) $2 AND @extschema@._intersects($1,$2)'
    LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;
```

In this case implicit index calls are performed as shown in the following query.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM QueryRegions R, berlinmod_trip T
WHERE intersects(R.Geom, T.Trip)

Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..278.50 rows=60 width=959)
  ->  Seq Scan on queryregions r  (cost=0.00..13.00 rows=100 width=847)
  ->  Index Scan using berlinmod_trip_spatial_idx on berlinmod_trip t  (cost=0.14..2.65 rows=1 width=112)
        Index Cond: (r.geom && trajectory(trip))
        Filter: _intersects(r.geom, trip)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be making this more complex then need be, two alternative methods of storing trajectories.

- Suggested method: create a `LINESTRING M` with each `POINT M`'s `M` dimension representing the offset since `t0`. This is the method that PostGIS standardizes around with [`ST_IsValidTrajectory`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidTrajectory.html), [`ST_DistanceCPA`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceCPA.html), and [`ST_AddMeasure`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AddMeasure.html)
- Normalize to a time interval with a `LINESTRING`: every `POINT` on the `LINESTRING` represents `t0 + numpoints-1`

Both of those scheme can be indexed simply and easily.

Answer (score 0):

First, your SQL function atPeriod cannot be inlined, as it contains a WHERE clause.

Second, even if it was inlined, I think that your test request will expand this way :

```
SELECT 
(SELECT @extschema@._atPeriod(Trip, Period) WHERE getTime(Trip)OPERATOR(@extschema@.&&) Period)
FROM QueryPeriods, berlinmod_trip
```

So the predicate will apply on the subrequest, thus not firing any indexes.

The behavior you are trying to produce doesn't exists in Postgis.
The inlinables functions that fires indexes are all spatial predicates, not spatial operations.

What you could do is writing a function like your interesects function that will encapsulates the test "does the timerange of this trip overlaps this timerange".